# Check my argument that this sequence does not converge.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

We want to show that $\{n^2+1\}$ does not converge. It's pretty clear that it doesn't converge, and this is only part of a true/false question so I don't really have to explain it, but I would like to make sure that I could prove it if needed.

I was thinking we could suppose that it does converge, and then so by our defintion of convergence, if the sequence has a limit at $L$, then

$\vert n^2 + 1 - L \vert$ $< \space \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \space > \space 0$ and $n \geq N$.

The next step that I was going to try, but I'm not sure about because I'm still amateur with inequalities, is that by the triangle inequality

$\vert n^2 + 1 \vert + \vert L \vert$ < $\epsilon$   (**?**)

Therefore, if we let $\epsilon = \vert L \vert$, then $\vert n^2 + 1 \vert$ $< 0$. But now we have a contradiction, all we do is pick an $n$ and insert it into our equation and we see that the inequality above can never be true, so therefore our sequence fails to meet the conditions of convergence.

My big question though is about the step I marked with the question mark. If this is wrong then a suggestion about how to proceed would be appreciated but if it is correct, could somebody please explain a bit as to why? I have a feeling it's correct but in mathematics I realized feelings aren't good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong,  because it's a misuse of the triangle inequality.   To show this, rewrite what you have as a + instead of a -, then use the triangle inequality, and you see that

$|n^2+1+(-L)|\le |n^2+1|+|L|$
Now, you originally had the left hand side is less than $\epsilon$.   You can't conclude the right hand side is also less than $\epsilon$,  they are not comparable by this logic.

There's a general fact you want to use here, and prove if you need to:  If a sequence converges, then it is bounded.

The simple proof to assume you have a convergent sequence, say $\{x_n\}$., converging to L.   Now, that means that I can pick a positive epsilon, so I'll pick 1,  such that there exists an $N\in \mathbb N$  such that $\forall n\ge N$,   $|x_n-L|<1$.   But then, removing the absolute value signs, we have $-1<x_n-L<1$,  so $-1-L<x_n<L+1$.   Hence we have all but a finite number of  $x_n$ are bounded below by $-1-L$ and bounded above by $1+L$.

Now,  take a look at the elements in the set $\{x_n|1\le n<N\}$.   This is a finite set, so it has a minimum and a maximum,  call those $A$ and $B$, .   Now, we have every element of the sequence is bounded below by $\min \{A,-L-1\}$,  and above by $\max \{B,L+1\}$.

Q.E.D.

Now, given this fact, all you have to do is show that your above sequence is unbounded (Obvious),  and you get it can't be convergent.

(as a side note,  cauchy also implies bounded)

Comment: Is this a correct way to show unboundedness? Since my sequence is $\{n^{2}+1\}$, if I assume that it is bounded, then there exists $M$ such that $n^{2} + 1 \leq M$ for all n. Subtracting 1 and taking the square root of both sides then I have that n is less than the square root of M, which by the Archimedean principle, I know the natural numbers are not bounded, so we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 1):

You have misused the triangles inequality. To prove divergence using your argument namely $$\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\exists M \in \mathbb{N}|n \ge M \to \left| {{n^2} + 1 - L} \right| < \varepsilon $$, we assume that this is correct for some $n$. Now, for $n+1$ we get $$\left| {{{(n + 1)}^2} + 1 - L} \right| = \left| {{n^2} + 1 - L + 2n + 1} \right|$$if $n$ is chosen to be large enough one could see that this leads to $$\left| {{{(n + 1)}^2} + 1 - L} \right| > 2n + 1 - \varepsilon $$ so that the distance of the next term is not a small number but nearly $2n$. Note that if you need to be really accurate, you should continue this argument again, this time for $n$ to show that this is also a non-convergent sequence.